# Flutter GestureDetector on tap

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

When making a scroll, the focus is on two CircleAvatar, and above each of them I put OnTap to add a specific action when clicking on one of them, but the problem is that OnTap does not work. How can this be solved with the same attached code?

Please help and thank you.

[image]

The code :

```
 class AddUserPage extends StatefulWidget {
      const AddUserPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
  State<AddUserPage> createState() => _AddUserPageState();
}

class _AddUserPageState extends State<AddUserPage> {
  final List<String> profiles = [
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-05_orig.png',
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-04_orig.png',
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-01_orig.png',
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-02_orig.png',
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-03_orig.png',
    // 'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-05_orig.png',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 250,
              child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                squeeze: 1.4,
                itemExtent: 150,
                diameterRatio: 9,
                onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {},
                physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
                  childCount: profiles.length ~/ 2 + profiles.length % 2,
                  builder: (context, index) => Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 50,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profiles[2 * index]),
                      ),),
                      if (2 * index + 1 < profiles.length)
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {},
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 50,
                          backgroundImage:
                              NetworkImage(profiles[2 * index + 1]),
                        ),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually this is not how `ListWheelScrollView` select items as much as i know, If you dont want magnification, you can try with general ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to use this package,

`https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view`

https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view

You will not have to make much changes since this package is very similar to  `ListWheelScrollView`.

Because,

`ListWheelScrollView` do not recognize `onTap()` on its children.